# How to check for correct url

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a current web app and we would like to determine if the page being requested is correct or not, we do this in a `Global.asax` on the `Application_BeginRequest` method, we check for the urls such as if someone enters `http://mywebtest/badurl` then we send them to a custom 404 page, but we are having trouble making it work when it has a .aspx extension, there are pages that are good with aspx extensions but others that do not exist should be fowarded to the custom 404. How can we do this?

```
If a page with .aspx is requested that does not exist, 
to redirect it to the custom 404  page?
```

I was trying something like (but its just a guess) and it did not work..

```
if ((string)System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Request.Path) == string.Empty)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("~/custom404.aspx");
                    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use [ASP.NET's Custom Error Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2f4e3e7.aspx) for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these links:

[File.Exists method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx)

[Check if URL exists](http://www.vcskicks.com/check-website.php)

[Display a Custom Error Page](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs)

Answer (score 0):

What do you get right now when someone enters a non-existent .aspx page? The standard ASP.net page not found error?

Usually, one would use the customErrors element of the Web.config. You can create a specific entry for the 404 status code:

```
<error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Errors/PageNotFound.aspx"/>
```